# Cassandra Token Aware

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra 1.2 cluster that is using vNodes (default of 256 per node). I'd like to predict the placement of these vNodes physically within the ring from within the client so I can more efficiently select a coordinator node per query.

I know that the vNodes are randomly spread around the ring so I'd need to query Cassandra at least once per client instance.

Any idea if it's possible? cassandra-sharp has what looks to be a stubbed class for selecting an EndPoint by it's row key: TokenAwareStrategy. But as far as I can tell it has no partitioning logic.
Has anyone done this before?

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CqlSharp](http://nuget.org/packages/CqlSharp/) has a working implementation of a TokenAware strategy. See the [CqlSharp wiki](https://github.com/reuzel/CqlSharp/wiki/Usage#using-a-partitionkey-to-route-a-query-to-responsible-replicas) on details how to use it.

The DataStax .net driver is under heavy development. I've seen that they are working on the same kind of logic, but I am unsure what the current state is.

Comment: Thanks! Must of missed CqlSharp. I had a go with the DataStax driver initially alongside cassandra-sharp and much preferred cassandra-sharp.

Comment: As the author of CqlSharp, I would love to hear your opinion on it... ;-)

Comment: It's very impressive. Get 250,000 records/s from 6 nodes no row cache: 50,000 faster than cassandra-sharp, with far less effort. We will be using your driver in our final product.  The threading and connection pool is much more configurable than c*-sharp. Have re-used ObjectAccessor and your attributes to build powerful schemas for our data. Very clean code. Only thing missing log4net plugging and proper XmlConfig, but using Spring.Net instead. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments. Always good to hear that your efforts are put to good use. Logging is on the wishlist. Xmlconfig should not be too hard to add too.